# AngularJS: ng-click of directive's child element not working

Tags: angularjs

I have set up the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X9ObEt8fiMqkCK5BZ19w?p=preview) to demonstrate the issue. The click of Bob button doesn't works. What I expected was, the child elements of the directive element will have the same isolated scope. Do I have to move the child elements into the template property of the directive?

Comment: why don't you just change the child button to `<button ng-click="setAppTitle('Bob')">Bob It!</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define some object `pass`.  Set up `pass` with method `setDirectiveTitle` and title:

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oxGX6cdJa3ihKJDAGIoi?p=preview)**</kbd>

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .directive("myScopedDirective", function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        pass: '=',
        prefix: "@msdTitle"
      },
      link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
        
        $scope.pass.setDirectiveTitle = function(title) {
         $scope.pass.title = $scope.prefix + title;
        } 
      }
    };
  })
  .controller("AppController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    
    $scope.passVal = {};
    
    $scope.setAppTitle = function(title) {
      $scope.passVal.title = title;
    };
  }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <button ng-click="setAppTitle('App 2.0')">Upgrade Me!</button>
      <div my-scoped-directive pass="passVal" msd-title="I'm a directive inside the app: {{passVal.title}}">
        <h2>{{passVal.title}}</h2>
        <button ng-click="passVal.setDirectiveTitle('Bob')"  >Bob It!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want the setDirectiveTitle() inside the directive scope only... can u tell me what is wrong with the original plunker?

Comment: Its ok, the implementation of `setDirectiveTitle` defined under directive with isolate scope. Here is all right. The idea is when user presses on `ngClick` we must fire this action and it will go to directive. I don't think you can do that by other way. Controller can't use `setDirectiveTitle` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that is not compiled, you have to use transclusion in order to compile html inside a directive.
http://plnkr.co/edit/hGKeTqqU62Na0MWPvBIZ?p=preview

Or you can simply pass an template:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYhTdlwSDp0L3jjErOQt?p=preview

But you cannot use scope attribute binding in this case. Because on second update of parent scope , third click on child will not be updated as you expected.
You have to propagate data differently.